# The discord bot wont assign a role

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am following Anson the Developers tutorial, ([here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgCJG8kkq50)) and I coded exactly as he did, I got no errors, except a warning `Parameter 'payload' value is not used`  and I have made sure that:

1. The bot has proper permissions to assign roles
2. The bot is online
3. The emojis and the roles have the same names

heres the code for reference:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

    if message_id == '756794977148993597':
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("member not found")
        else:
            print("role not found")
 
client.run('REDACTED')
```

I have tried a lot of troubleshooting and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I got no errors while running your code but it also didnt work. To make it work though i just removed the `''` by `if message_id == '(message id)'` so that it was just `if message_id == (message id)`

Comment: In other words, the error is that message_id is an int but OP is checking it against a string version of their message id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `utils.find` in your case.

- [client.get_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) to get the guild by id.
- [guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) to get the member by id. also you can use `guild.get_member_named` if you want to use a name.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 756794977148993597:
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji.name)

        if role is not None:
            member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print("done")
            else:
                print("member not found")
        else:
            print("role not found")
```